# How to find out the dimension of the lightbox?

Tags: javascript

About the lightboxes. The box adjusts its dimension to match the picture. Question is how do the box find out the size of the picture?

Comment: fu required - at least 15 characters

Answer (score 1):

To answer the comment about detecting when its done loading, i believe you can use the onLoad event. in jquery this would look somthing like:

`$('img').attr('src', 'uri/for/image').load(callbackFunction);`

or manually:

```
var tmp = new Image();
tmp.onload = callbackFunction;
tmp.src = 'uri/for/image';
```

your `callbackFunction` could then use `$(this).height()` and `$(this).height()` safely. so your `callbackFunction` is where you would have the actual logic to trigger the rest of your implementation.

in alot of cases if seen this callback (or its equiv. implementation) simply set a global variable and then somewhere else in the code youll see polling of this variable every N ms. and when its set it will trigger the rest of the script.

Answer (score 0):

I assume something akin to:

```
imgWidth = $(img).width();
imgHeight = $(img).height();
```

It would load the image in a hidden element (or positioned off screen), get the dimensions, animate the container to fit, then expose the image (usually via some sort of transition/animation).

Comment: and how do i know when the pic finish downloading?